# Node script modules how to properly reference within html

Tags: javascript, node.js, reference, module

I'm putting together a solution with Node, Express and Angular. I've installed the node Angular package, but I'm not sure how to properly reference the library in my html. Do I need to configure a custom route outside of the public folder to achieve this?

Ideally, i'd like a solution that is analogous to the ASP.Net script bundle, where I can reference a named bundle, or Node script module in my html.

**Edit**

What I'm specifically trying to build right now is a test harness page that allows me to visualize Mocha unit tests, which necessitates client side script references to Mocha, Chai and Angular. It doesn't seem that keeping redundant copies of these libraries, or using a CDN reference for just the client side html is clean.

What is the best way to do this in Node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `angular` module in npm is for **using** angular server-side via jsdom. If you need it client-side for browsers, just download a copy from angular's website.

The only other way you could include the `angular` npm module client-side is if you were using browserify, which would also work.